# insert data checked in data table checkbox codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am doing a project for my school subject. I am confused on how to do checking data's in checkbox and when I press a submit button, it will loop to insert into my database. I manage to display/alert the data that is being checked in my data-table.

Here is my Contoller where it populates my data table:

```
public function getalldocs() {
    $listdocs = $this->Admin_model->getdoctors();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($listdocs as $docs) {
        $row = array();  
        $row[] = $docs->user_fname;
        $row[] = $docs->user_mname;
        $row[] = $docs->user_lname;
        $row[] = '<input name="user_id[]" value="'.$docs->user_id.'" type="checkbox">';

        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(   
        "data" => $data,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Here is in my view:

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <table id="dataTables-docs"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable dtr-inline" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" aria-describedby="dataTables-material">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div><!-- dataTable_wrapper -->
```

here is my javascript to echo the selected check box from my data-table:

```
function show_docs() {
    $("#dataTables-docs").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    table =  $('#dataTables-docs').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_controls/getalldocs')?>",
            "type": "POST",
        },
        responsive: true,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        'bInfo': false,
        'paging': false
    });
}

$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    var user_id = $(this).val();
    alert(user_id);
});
```

now, i want to all that is being checked to be inserted in my database like this:
(myid,selectedfromcheckbox);
here is my screenshot from database table:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use another ajax to insert the data

```
$('#dataTables-docs tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    var user_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          data: {user_id:user_id},
         "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin_controls/saveData')?>",
          success:function(data){
             $("#info").html(data);
          }

      });
});
```

// Below code in you controller

```
public function saveData()
{
// code to save in controler
}
```

Comment: The function will be called once the check box is clicked.So no need of loop

Comment: what if i will uncheck? then need to update again? can you give me some code to alert if uncheck?

Comment: Hello .. How can i condition if the checkbox is checked or unchecked?